# Change the image when selecting a modification

Tags: javascript, html, liquid

There is an image change code when clicking.

```html
        <div class="product-image">
           <img itemprop="image" id="productimage" src="{{product.first_image.large_url}}" style="width: 100%" title="{{product.title}}">
        </div>  
        {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
        <div class="gallery">
        {% for image in product.images %}
           <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('productimage').src='{{image.original_url}}'" style="background: url({{image.medium_url}}) center center no-repeat; background-size: 100%;" title="{{ product.title | escape }}"></a>
        {% endfor %} 
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

(Online store on Liquid)

And there is a code for changing the images of goods when selecting a selector (modification).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.single-option-selector').change(function() {
    return imgchange($(this).find(':selected').text());
  });
</script>
```

I can not understand in any way how to associate JS and function OnClick at all.
I'm very weak in Javascript.
I tried to implement OnClick function in the selector itself. None of this did not work out.
Help please understand.

My selector code:

```html
              {% if product.show_variants? %}
              <hr>
              <select name="variant_id" data-product-variants>
     {% for variant in product.variants %}
                {% if variant.quantity > 0 %}
       <option name="variant_id" id="variant-select" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title | escape }}</option>
                {% else %}
       <option name="variant_id" id="variant-select" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title | escape }} (OUT)</option>                
                {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
     </select>
              {% endif %}
```

Excuse me, I do not even understand what I need to ask to do this.

Comment: So changing the value of the dropdown will change the img? You just want to trigger that change?

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1400 Yes. Yes. Yes!

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if you can hit the dropdown. it should popout a alert dialog

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion first for you.
I think you should declare your change function like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.single-option-selector').change(function() {
    return imgchange($(this).find(':selected').text());
  })
});
</script>
```

It sets the change event when the DOM is ready.

For the rest @Monkey_Dev1400 has a good point